# Magento 1.9 Fatal error: Call to a member function getBackend() on boolean

Tags: magento-1.9, product

I want to make a simple module who show product details without header footer and other block. At first i try to get product info by id. But that say

> Fatal error: Call to a member function getBackend() on boolean in D:\x\htdocs\m1\app\code\core\Mage\Eav\Model\Entity\Abstract.php on line 816

My code

```
class Abdus_Ajaxproduct_LoadproductController extends Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action{
public function getbyidAction(){
    $_prdID=$this->getRequest()->getParam('id');
    $_product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()->addFieldToFilter('id',$_prdID);
}}
```

Comment: try `Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($_prdID);` does that work?

Comment: Yes It work, and more I realize if I use sku then my code work properly. only problem when call ID.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use:

```
 Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($_prdID);
```

Instead of:

```
Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()->addFieldToFilter('id',$_prdID);
```

Answer (score 2):

For the later comers:

```
Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()->addFieldToFilter('entity_id',$_prdID);
```

From the point of view of an EAV model, there is no such field called "id".